# Modx revo расширение CKEditor отключить проверку на валидацию парных тегов

Tags: modx, ckeditor, revo

Отключить валидацию на проверку парных тегов

`</div>` //после сохранения удаляет тег div

`<p>some text</p>`

## Пример

1) http://prntscr.com/fsbx1e //когда нажимаешь на источник, что бы посмотреть на код

2) http://prntscr.com/fsbx1e //открывается такое окно

3) http://prntscr.com/fsbxvt //прописываешь закрывающиеся тег

4) нажимаешь еще раз на "Источник" показывает снова текст, а когда нажимаешь посмотреть код, то закрывающийся тег удался.

## Как сделать так что бы не удалялись закрывающиеся теги?

Comment: Все картинки вы можете вставить прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Если тебе нужно отключать такие вещи - то ты явно чтото делаешь в этой жизни не так...

Comment: @Vasis и не говори, какой-то бекенчик наделал делов, а я смотрю и переделываю, проблема была в том что  создано куча ресурсов в которых куча закрывающихся тегов в начале textaera, а открывающиеся в чанках, пришлось переделывать верстку

Answer (score 0):

Скажу, одно это глупо и ненужно делать, так как если будет закрываться много тегов, то будут закрываться и теги самого плагина и все поломается.

Кому будет нужен вот код:

\admin\assets\components\ckeditor\ckeditor\config.js  //путь к файлу

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
      config.allowedContent = true;
      config.protectedSource.push(//g); //разрешает все закрывающиеся теги
      // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
      // config.language = 'fr';
      // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    };
```